# ReactJs - passing state to route using default visual studio example app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio

I'm completely new to ReactJs so trying to learn the best practices.  I am using the default react project created via visual studio, which has routing set up and three tabs, Home, Counters and FetchData.

I have some state in the Counters class - which when on the particular page edits as desired, however every time I navigate away and then back it resets to the initial state rather than the altered state?

Can anyone explain why this is?  It seems to be hitting the render method each time you click on a tab, which I guess means its creating a new instance each time rather than reusing. Is there anyway to get around this?

Also I was trying to pass down some state information to the counters class, is this possible with the route?

```
export class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {

    state = {
        counters: [
            new CounterObject(1, 4),
            new CounterObject(2, 0),
            new CounterObject(3, 1)
        ]
    }

    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/counter' component={Counters} />
                    <Route path='/fetchdata' component={FetchData} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The component will be unmounted when the route changes and it is no longer in use, and then a new instance is mounted again when you go back. Because of this the state in the component will be reset.

You can use the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop if you want to pass down props to the route component.

**Example**

```
export class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {
  state = {
    counters: [
      new CounterObject(1, 4),
      new CounterObject(2, 0),
      new CounterObject(3, 1)
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-3">
            <NavMenu />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-9">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route
              path="/counter"
              render={() => <Counters counters={this.state.counters} />}
            />
            <Route path="/fetchdata" component={FetchData} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you for this response, i've tried to do this render, but i'm getting an error (TS) Type '{} is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProbs<{}>>, any ideas with this?

Comment: @user3284707 You're welcome! I've never used React Router with TypeScript, so I don't know, I'm afraid. [This might help](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/13689).

Comment: On another note, is there a way that it won't unmount so the state stays the same?

Comment: @user3284707 I don't think there is. If you have some state that you want to persists between page changes, you must put it in the parent component and pass it down as props, or use a state management library like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) or [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux).